# Is it correct that this DataStore service depends on the Serialization service?

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, service

There is a `IDataStore` interface which has this contract:

```
public interface IDataStore
{
    Task<T> CreateEntity<T>(string entityName, string entityId, T entity);
    Task<T> GetEntity<T>(string entityName, string entityId);
}
```

One of it's implementation is the `FileSystemDataStore`:

```
public class FileSystemDataStore : IDataStore
{
    private readonly ISerializer _serializer;
    public Task<T> CreateEntity<T>(string entityName, string entityId, T entity)
    {
        var obj = (object?)entity;

        /*
         * Convert entity to obj ot type Object
         * Serialize obj which the _serializer service 
         * and store it in the file system under entityName/entityId.myExtension
         */

        return Task.FromResult(entity);
    }

    public Task<T> GetEntity<T>(string entityName, string entityId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Note the commented Code**

`FileSystemDataStore` now has `ISerializer` injected, so when configuring the DI container we must explicitly provide the `ISerializer` implementation.

**In a large application with a big dependency graph, isn't this a high risk of a mess of circular dependencies ? What is the correct way of solving this simple problem which can be applied on large projects?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `FileSystemDataStore` some type of implementation of repository pattern. It is better to keep without any logic. It should have only CRUD logic. Why? Because repositories are to execute only some CRUD logic.

So I would suggest to move serialization logic into business layer instead of mixing Serialization with DAL.

Comment: I separated the data access classes into 2 categories: `IDataStore` and `IRepository<T>`. `IDatStore` classes are used to save to a particular database type (file system, Azure storage, MongoDB, etc.) while `Repository<T>` classes deal with the entities specific logic and use the service `IDataStore`. For ex: `CarRepository: IRepository<Car>` which is injected with the `IDataStore` service.

Comment: The serialization class is used as a general purpose service. It serializes object into a string  with the type information required to deserialize it back into an object

Comment: Note also these are part of infrastructure layer. So they should be domain agnostic

Comment: @EEAH is IDataStore repository? IDataStore and CarRepository injected into some service?

Comment: No IDataStore is not a repository. It's used for different storage types (Azure, postgres, filesystem, etc.). IRepository deals with sepcific entities. It uses the IDataStore to store some data in storage.

Comment: For ex: `GraphQlDataStore: IDataStore` would have the method "CreateEntityRelation(string sourceId, string targetId, sourceEntity, targetEntity)" This method will call GrqphQL specific logic to create that relation. While `SQLDataStore: IDataStore` will have the same method signature but with a different implementation (with sql)